# Is there a way to send a scan request to a printer using python OS library?

Tags: python, python-os

I'm currently building a text based console application to manage printing, scanning, etc but as usuall i have stumped my self and have had to come to stackoverflow for help.
Any help is appreciated.

I have imported the os library.

```
import os
```

But unsure of a function to scan.

Comment: what are you trying to scan specifically?

Comment: What OS are you using? What scanner are you using? How is it attached (USB/Ethernet)?

Comment: Can you share the command you use to scan when not using Python, i.e. when using the regular command-line?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I am trying to scan a document. (I normally use windows fax and scan)

Comment: My printer/scanner is a HP envy series and is wireless

Comment: Hi carp-tango, Check if this solution works for you:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12723818/print-to-standard-printer-from-python

Comment: Hi, Kai unfortunately it doesn't. thank you for your help though.

Comment: What happened when you tried the advice at that link? How is that different from what you want to happen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Scanning

You can check this library called [LibInsane](https://doc.openpaper.work/libinsane/latest/libinsane/install.html) to scan from printers using Python. But to install the library you're going to have to build the library from the source.

##### Install the [LibInsane](https://doc.openpaper.work/libinsane/latest/libinsane/install.html) library

- You will find the [necessary instructions here to build the library](https://doc.openpaper.work/libinsane/latest/libinsane/install.html)

##### How to use Libinsane in a Python program

###### command line

The latter 2 commands must be run inside the libinsane directory. You can navigate to the example sample projects and run:

- for listing devices

```
python list_device.py
```

- for scanning documents

```
python scan.py outputfilename.png
```

###### python script

Modify the `.py` file paths and the output image path before running it

```
import os

# for listing devices
devices = os.system("python list_device.py")

# for listing devices
scanned_doc = os.system("python scan.py outputfilename.png")
```

##### This is what the `scan.py` file contains

```
def scan(source, output_file):
    session = source.scan_start()
 
    try:
        page_nb = 0
        while not session.end_of_feed() and page_nb < 20:
            # Do not assume that all the pages will have the same size !
            scan_params = session.get_scan_parameters()
            print("Expected scan parameters: {} ; {}x{} = {} bytes".format(
                  scan_params.get_format(),
                  scan_params.get_width(), scan_params.get_height(),
                  scan_params.get_image_size()))
            total = scan_params.get_image_size()
 
            img = []
            r = 0
            if output_file is not None:
                out = output_file.format(page_nb)
            else:
                out = None
            print("Scanning page {} --> {}".format(page_nb, out))
            while not session.end_of_page():
                data = session.read_bytes(128 * 1024)
                data = data.get_data()
                img.append(data)
                r += len(data)
                print("Got {} bytes => {}/{} bytes".format(
                    len(data), r, total)
                )
            img = b"".join(img)
            print("Got {} bytes".format(len(img)))
            if out is not None:
                print("Saving page as {} ...".format(out))
                if scan_params.get_format() == Libinsane.ImgFormat.RAW_RGB_24:
                    img = raw_to_img(scan_params, img)
                    img.save(out, format="PNG")
                else:
                    print("Warning: output format is {}".format(
                        scan_params.get_format()
                    ))
                    with open(out, 'wb') as fd:
                        fd.write(img)
            page_nb += 1
            print("Page {} scanned".format(page_nb))
        if page_nb == 0:
            print("No page in feeder ?")
    finally:
        session.cancel()
```

You can read more from the [official documentation here](https://doc.openpaper.work/libinsane/latest/libinsane/howto_python.html)

#### Printing

To print from a specific printer using python, check out this answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/76981889/13520498